Bootstrap multiple buttons get text of only the button pressed
Using the answers posted from here, I created a button group. However when I press the button, the text shown in the alert box returns all the buttons that are pressed, how can I make it so that only the button pressed gets returned?


$(".btn-group> .btn").on("click", function() {
  console.log($('.btn-group> .btn').text());
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
</div>




There's no excuse for not creating a simple demo for this at your rep level. Do better, please. Also, virtually every question has been asked and answered about jQuery. It's a very old and stable library. Please search first.

This selector returns all of the matching elements:
$('.btn-group> .btn')

So reasonably this would either return all of the text, or potentially default to the first matching text (it's the latter):
$('.btn-group> .btn').text()

You don't need to re-select the elements in the first place though.  If you just want the element which was clicked, this refers to that in jQuery's event handlers:


$(".btn-group> .btn").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).text()); 
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
</div>




This should work for you
$(".btn-group > .btn").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).text()); 
});

